# function is returning numbers instead of letters

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a function that will return the last letter of each word in a string, and think I am close, but whenever I invoke the function, I get a series of numbers instead of the letters I am looking for.

This is the code:

```
function lastLetter(str){
    var arr = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i++){
        if(str[i] === " " || str[i] === "."){
            arr.push((i) - 1);
        }

    }
     return arr;
}
lastLetter("I love bacon and eggs.");
```

Any advice would be appreciated.  Thanks!!

Comment: You push numbers in the array `arr.push((i) - 1);`, so what do you expect then.

Comment: What if a string stars with a space?

Comment: Reconsider your algorithm for inputs like `" foo"` or `"bar..."`.

Answer (score 3):

You push the value `i - 1` onto the array. You meant to push `str.charAt(i-1)`:

```
arr.push(str.charAt(i - 1));
```

See: [String charAt()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_charat.asp).

Note that your code isn't really defensive. If there is a space or period at the first character in the string, you are referencing the character at position `-1`, which is not valid. You could solve this by looping from `1` instead of `0`. In that case you would still get a space in the result if the string starts with two spaces, but at least you won't get an error. A slightly better version of the algorithm would test if `i-1` is a valid index, and if there is a character at that position that is not a space or a period.

Below is a possible solution, which I think solves those cases, while still retaining the structure of the code as you set it up.

```js
function lastLetter(str){
    var arr = [];
    for(var i = 1; i < str.length; i++){
        var p = str.charAt(i-1);
        var c = str.charAt(i);
        if ( (c === " " || c === ".") &&
            !(p === " " || p === ".") ) {
            arr.push(p);
        }
    }
     return arr;
}

console.log(lastLetter("... Do you love bacon and eggs..."));
```

Comment: Wow, that was quick!  That really helps!  I'm pretty new to coding, so it's nice to be able to get help so quickly.  I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
arr.push(str[i - 1]);
```

This will have problems with multi-byte characters, however.

Answer (score 0):

You're pushing the integer value `i-1` rather than the character `str[i-1]`.

Answer (score 0):

You are pushing the index into your array.  You still  need to access i-1 of your string
`

```
` function lastLetter(str){
    var arr = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i++){
        if(str[i] === " " || str[i] === "."){
            arr.push(str[(i) - 1]);
        }

    }
     return arr;
}
lastLetter("I love bacon and eggs.");
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution and Improved version below:

use `arr.push(str.charAt(i - 1))` instead of `arr.push((i) - 1)`
(You where saving the position of the last letter, but not it's value - `charAt(position)` does give you the latter at the given position

`charAt()`: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_charat.asp

Demo:

```js
function lastLetter(str){
    var arr = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i++){
        if(str[i] === " " || str[i] === "."){
            arr.push(str.charAt(i - 1));
        }

    }
     return arr;
}

document.body.innerHTML = lastLetter("I love bacon and eggs.");
```

Improved Version:

```js
function lastLetter(str) {
  var arr = [];
  var words = str.split(/[\s\.?!:]+/)
  for (var i = 0; i < words.length; ++i) {
    if (words[i].length > 0) {
      var lastLetter = words[i].charAt(words[i].length - 1)
      arr.push(lastLetter);
    }
  }
  return arr;
}

document.body.innerHTML = lastLetter("... Is this: correct?! I love bacon and eggs.");
```